# how to fill_in textfield with capybara:selenium in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

how to fill_in textfield with capybara:selenium in rails?

i have code like this :

```
it 'anonymous upload', :js => true do
    visit '/'
    page.find("#upload-bill-anonymous").click
    path = DATA_TEST+SUCCESS
    attach_file("bill", path)
    page.find("div#submitbutton.wizard-1").click
    fill_in 'user_email', :with => "test@local.com"
    page.find("div#submitbutton.wizard-2").click
    page.find("#link-resend").click
  end
```

with selenium fill_in i get error like this 
"Failure/Error: fill_in 'user_email', :with => 'test@local.com'
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError:"

Answer (score 0):

user_email is id? If yes should working. also you can try:

```
page.find(:css, "#user_email").set("test@local.com")
```

Comment: still not working, i get error "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError Exception: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"

Comment: if you found the problem please write solution. Will be for other people's